# Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Lat 5591: Ethernet Card not showing

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

My Ethernet card is not showing on `lspci`. All I can do is use wireless which does not help me in my current state. Is this a dead ethernet card or something else? 
lspci below (only wifi showing):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a363 (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a338 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33d (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15db (rev 02)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 2263 (rev 03)
```

Comment: Check if it is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Look at your startup logs with  `journalctl -b 0`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with:
Fedora 5.2.9-200.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 16 21:37:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I think there is some specific driver missing. I was searching on intel site, but without success. I will try to find out what is "00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)"

I figured it out. The problem was that in the BIOS the networking device for LAN wasn't activated

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, the problem was that in bios network device for lan wasn't activated.